# Действующее или действительное?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, паронимы

Возник вопрос при составлении документа. В контексте я должен употребить «проверка действующего удостоверения» или «действительного»? Я склоняюсь к «действительному», так как хочу сказать о проверке удостоверения на легитимность. То есть соответствует ли удостоверение (его формат, срок годности и т. д.) нормам. Спасибо!

Comment: Обращайте внимание на метки, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Если говорить о *легитимности* удостоверения, то выражение нужно изменить на "*проверка действительно**сти** удостоверения*" (= действительно оно или нет), поскольку в исходном виде из выражения буквально следует, что берётся *действительное* (легитимное, т. е. подлинное, и действующее, т. е. *не просроченное*) удостоверение и зачем-то его предлагается проверить на какой-то предмет.
Пример "проверки **действительности**" из официальной практики: http://services.fms.gov.ru/

"Проверка *действующего* удостоверения" означала бы, что проверяют на какой-то предмет (напр. на факт наличия его у человека - для подтверждения полномочий, на принадлежность его именно этому человеку и т. п.) удостоверение, срок действия которого не истёк, а форма не устарела (её могли отменить в какой-то момент).

Comment: Должно быть существительное, вы правы.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь нет и не может быть однозначной рекомендации. Это профессиональный жаргон, а он разный в разных сферах. Зависит даже от традиций и внутренних правил учреждения.

Юристы, насколько знаю, склоняются к термину ***"действующий"***, для них это и есть всё то, что вы описали термином "действительный". Ну а для какой-нибудь охранной конторы "действительный", согласен, звучит лучше.